# How to stop my UILabel from wrapping unexpectedly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` set in storyboard with Lines=0 and stretched big enough for 2 or 3 lines.
But when I run, and I set `UILabel` to a sentence of text, it injects a line feed after each of the first few words.

I set `.text = "GPS 37.664051,-121.910774"`
but it then displays as:

GPS
37.6640
43,-121.9
10789

My `UILabel` is stretched across the screen horizontally, and stretched vertically to obviously allow up to 4 lines.

Init:

```
self.loggedInLabel.text = @"RUNNING";
self.loggedInLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[self.loggedInLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Your call to `sizeToFit` changes everything.

Comment: Line =0 means hold any number of lines. [self.loggedInLabel sizeToFit]; adjust text based on intrinsic content size. Instead use sizeThatFit:(CGSize) method and pass available width of label.

Comment: I tried this but get an error:  [self.loggedInLabel sizeThatFit:(  self.loggedInLabel.frame.size.width )];